# is there any way to deploy my app built in XCode3.1.2 with My Mac10.5.8 to iphone4(SDK4)?

Tags: iphone

I just want to test the app in a real device, but it seems the SDK does not match, I only have a 10.5.8 Mac and can not upgrade to 10.6 rightnow, then I could not get the lastest SDK version 4.

Any method to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a distribution version of your app (signed with a distribution provisioning profile, *get-task-allow* set to *false* in *Entitlements.plist* etc.) and package it in a .ipa file, then you can install it via iTunes onto your device and test it.

However, it won't be possible to install it from XCode or to debug it because XCode insists on having a matchin SDK. And that's only included with more recent versions of XCode.

Comment: I suspect you can also install Development apps with iTunes, and iPhone Configuration Utility should also work unless they've restricted that to be 10.6+.

Comment: codo's solution works, all i need to do is to create an ad-hoc profile and install it in my device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming two things:

- You have iPhone SDK 3.1 or 3.1.2 for Leopard installed (I can't find a release that includes Xcode 3.1.2; maybe I missed OS 3.1.1).
- You have a device running iOS 4 (the fact that it's an iPhone 4 is largely irrelevant).

To get Xcode to talk to the phone, you need the relevant DeviceSupport directory (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport). You can extract the files from the iOS 4.0 SDK directly (Flat Package Editor/pkgutil/lsbom/cpio/ditto, or just use Pacifist) and move them to the right places. I'm not sure if the 4.0 device support works with Xcode 3.1.2 — there's a pretty big chance that it won't (oh well).

If you do this, you'll additionally have to extract the SDK directory and move it to DeviceSupports/4.whatever/Symbols (over the symlink), or GDB won't be able to find any symbols.

Additionally, it *might* be possible to "install" the 4.0 SDK by extracting the files and moving them to the right place. Again, this is a bit underhanded/unsupported. You might find that there are some components (GCC 4.2) that work, while others (the 4.0 simulator, Xcode, Interface Builder) don't.

At the end of the day, it's easier to just head down to the Apple Store and buy a copy of SL than to faff with SDK upgrades. I call it the Apple Tax.